# Iframe scroll bar is not visible in Android phones

Tags: android, iframe, scroll

I am using this code:

```
<div>
    <iframe class="careers" frameborder="0" height="1000px" scrolling="yes"
            src="http://intranet.pamten.com/careers/currentopenings.aspx" width="100%">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

the problem is when I am seeing in Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (Android) mobile scrolling is happening but scroll bar is not visible.

Can anybody please help me on this issue.....

Answer (score 0):

Scroll bar will be hidden for `iframe` in the following situations,

- Using the `seamless` property for your iframe tag hides the scroll bar.
- As you are testing in Tab, it is possible the `width` you have given to class 'careers' will be out of screen, hides the scrollbar.
- Also possible to hide the scrollbar using the `css` property. Check it out if any.

Please note, by default iframe scroll bar will be shown for any screen size width.